# Flask will only log if debug is true

Tags: python, debugging, logging, flask

I have recently created a flask app that streams a video to my local network. This is on a raspberry pi. I have attempted to make a log file using this code::

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(filename='error.log',level=logging.DEBUG)
```

When I run the flask app with app.run(), the app will not log anything to the error.log file. But, when I run it with debug=true , then the app logs all info. The error.log file when I run it looks like this:

```
INFO:werkzeug:10.0.0.127 - - [10/Feb/2018 16:37:40] "GET /video_feed HTTP/1.1" $
INFO:werkzeug:10.0.0.127 - - [10/Feb/2018 16:37:40] "GET /static/css/bootstrap.$
INFO:werkzeug:10.0.0.127 - - [10/Feb/2018 16:39:45] "GET /video_feed HTTP/1.1" $
INFO:werkzeug:10.0.0.127 - - [10/Feb/2018 16:40:08] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
INFO:werkzeug:10.0.0.127 - - [10/Feb/2018 16:40:08] "GET /video_feed HTTP/1.1" $
INFO:werkzeug:10.0.0.127 - - [10/Feb/2018 16:40:09] "GET /logs HTTP/1.1" 200 -
INFO:werkzeug:10.0.0.127 - - [10/Feb/2018 16:40:10] "GET /invalidpass HTTP/1.1"$
INFO:werkzeug:10.0.0.127 - - [10/Feb/2018 16:40:21] "GET /logs HTTP/1.1" 200 -
INFO:werkzeug:10.0.0.127 - - [10/Feb/2018 16:40:29] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
INFO:werkzeug:10.0.0.127 - - [10/Feb/2018 16:40:30] "GET /video_feed HTTP/1.1" $
INFO:werkzeug:10.0.0.127 - - [10/Feb/2018 16:40:31] "GET /logout HTTP/1.1" 302 -
INFO:werkzeug:10.0.0.127 - - [10/Feb/2018 16:40:31] "GET /welcome HTTP/1.1" 302$
INFO:werkzeug:10.0.0.127 - - [10/Feb/2018 16:40:31] "GET /login HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

I was wondering if it is possible to not have the Debug on when I run my flask app, and still log all information to the error.log file. I have tried switching the level to logging.INFO but that has not worked.

Comment: might want to check out http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/dev/logging/

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the logging level to error.

```
logging.basicConfig(filename='error.log',level=logging.ERROR)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the log level for the root logger but as mentioned in the [flask logging docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/dev/logging/) flask configures its own logger in the 'flask' logging namespace.

The application logger is available as a property on the application object. Do

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

if you'd like to always show logs at DEBUG level.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't figure out which way I wanted to go with logging that way, so I decided to create my own logging instance, and then log any info I wanted to it, which seemed to work. Although this is a longer and manual process, it let me control what was logged and how it was logged. The code looked similar to this::

```
#Import requests from flask to log things such as form data and other requests made to the server
from flask import request
#import python logging for logging to files
import logging
from logging.handlers import RotatingFileHandler
#How I logged the information I wanted to log
logInfo = 'Info on Login: ' +  'IP: ' + request.remote_addr
    app.logger.info(logInfo)

#Create the logging instance test

handler = RotatingFileHandler('error.log', maxBytes=10000, backupCount=1)
handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
app.logger.addHandler(handler)
app.logger.info('INFO TEST')
```